# How to trim an NSImage by giving bounds

Tags: macos, nsimage

I have an NSImage object, I have an CIDetector object that detects QR codes on that image. After it detects, I wants to trim that image so it only has the QR code in it. This is how I've got the bounds of the QR code:

```
NSArray *features = [myQRDetector featureInImage:myCIImage];
CIQRCodeFeature *qrFeature = features[0];
CGRect qrBounds = qrFeature.bounds;
```

Now how can I trim the image so it only contains the area described by `qrBounds` variable.

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 5

```
func trim(image: NSImage, rect: CGRect) -> NSImage {
    let result = NSImage(size: rect.size)
    result.lockFocus()

    let destRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: result.size)
    image.draw(in: destRect, from: rect, operation: .copy, fraction: 1.0)

    result.unlockFocus()
    return result
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. But this seems to create a new image that it's always an 8-bit integer RGBA image. If the source is a 16-bit float image, how can I make the result to match the source? The constructor of NSImage doesn't take any hints of the data I'm storing...

Comment: Beware: `lockFocus()` is now deprecated

Comment: Absolutely Fantastic this save my day. Thanks 

Answer (score 3):

The [answer from onmyway133](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56622501/1765629) is great, but it doesn't preserve the datatype of the source image. For instance, if your source is an `.hdr` image, each color channel will be floats, but the cropped image will be an 8-bit integer RGBA image.

For preserving the format of the source, it seems you have to go down to the associated `CGImage`. I do this:

```swift
extension NSImage {
    func cropping(to rect: CGRect) -> NSImage {
        var imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        guard let imageRef = self.cgImage(forProposedRect: &imageRect, context: nil, hints: nil) else {
            return NSImage(size: rect.size)
        }
        guard let crop = imageRef.cropping(to: rect) else {
            return NSImage(size: rect.size)
        }
        return NSImage(cgImage: crop, size: NSZeroSize)
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid this. There are many problems with this code: cgImage can be double size, so `rect` will use mismatched coordinates; if for some reasons it can't create the cropped image, e.g. if the rect is larger than the image, then it'll just return an empty image, complicating troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new `NSImage` and draw the part of the original image you want to it.

```
NSImage* newImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSSizeFromCGSize(qrBounds.size)];
[newImage lockFocus];
NSRect dest = { NSZeroPoint, newImage.size };
[origImage drawInRect:dest fromRect:NSRectFromCGRect(qrBounds) operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1];
[newImage unlockFocus];
```